# SIP linux client to block unwanted calls

Tags: linux, sip, voip

I would like to have the possibility to block certain SIP incoming calls based on the caller id.

My idea so far is to have a linux box with a sip client that when recives the call (INVITE) it simply checks the caller id against a list and if in the list it hang up (BYE). No voice no media flow needed, just the possibility to register to the SIP server and hang up.

Any idea or any software that already does that?
How would you suggest doing this? (osip, sipp, exosip...)

thank you, 
dk

ps: I have no access to SIP server, and I cannot have a sip proxy/server like asterisk that blocks the calls for me, I can just have a client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re sip library](http://creytiv.com/re.html) to create a very basic sip client . Please check the code in the link for a basic sip client. http://pastebin.com/4uDWQf1B

To block by certain caller_id use the code below in connect_handler function .

```
if(!pl_strcmp(&msg->from.uri.user,"your_caller_id")){
    (void)sip_treply(NULL, sip, msg, 486, "Busy Here");
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't know this library, in the mean time I tried pjsip. It seems nice and I'm modifying the call.py python example.. so far it seems to work nice.